# Unable to pass parameter value in Concat select Prepared statements

Tags: mysql

I found the stored procedure does not execute only this portion:

```
          SET @sql 
          = CONCAT('SELECT TraineeID, ', @sql, ' 
                    from tbl_submit_coursefee c
                    where c.BatchID='BID'
                    group by c.TraineeID');
```

in where clause `''` quotes do not allow and without quotes query return empty but if I put the parameter value in where clause straight then it works. I'm really stack with this.

Here is my prepared statement (working fine):

```
SET @sql = NULL;    
SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT ('MAX(IF(BillNo = ''', BillNo, ''', CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.', BillNo, '`') 
         )  INTO @sql
    FROM tbl_submit_coursefee
    WHERE BatchID="ID-Welding/FMMTTC-01M/R8/01";

    SET @sql 
      = CONCAT('SELECT TraineeID, ', @sql, ' 
                from tbl_submit_coursefee c
                where c.BatchID="ID-Welding/FMMTTC-01M/R8/01"
                group by c.TraineeID');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

when put this statement in a stored procedure (not working):

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE GetRetainment @@
CREATE PROCEDURE vtproject.GetRetainment
(IN `BID` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT ('MAX(IF(BillNo = '', BillNo, '', CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.', BillNo, '`') 
        )   INTO @sql
    FROM tbl_submit_coursefee
    WHERE BatchID=BID;

    SET @sql 
      = CONCAT('SELECT TraineeID, ', @sql, ' 
                from tbl_submit_coursefee c
                where c.BatchID='BID'
                group by c.TraineeID');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

If I `select @sql` before `prepare stmt FROM @sql` then output as below:

```
SELECT TraineeID, MAX(IF(BillNo = 1, CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.1`,MAX(IF(BillNo = 2, CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.2`,MAX(IF(BillNo = 3, CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.3`,MAX(IF(BillNo = 4, CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.4`,MAX(IF(BillNo = 5, CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.5`,MAX(IF(BillNo = 6, CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.6`,MAX(IF(BillNo = 7, CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.7` from tbl_submit_coursefee c where c.BatchID=BID group by c.TraineeID
```

Comment: what is output `select @sql; ` just before `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;`

i think `BID` should be like this `''BID''` two double quotes means you are using it as escape char

Comment: `''BID''` double quotes doest not taken yet, and I just update what return if I set `select @sql`before `prepare stmt From @sql`. please take look.

Comment: if I use "BID" then mysql return empty result

Comment: What is this `BID` some variable or `Value` ?

Comment: "ID-Welding/FMMTTC-01M/R8/01"

Comment: Then put two `''` single quotes starting `BID` and two single quotes ending. like `''BID''` and then run the procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126085/discussion-between-mir-abzal-ali-and-unknown-user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in another way myself.

```
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @bid=BID;
SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT ('MAX(IF(BillNo = ', BillNo, ', CRA, NULL)) AS `Inv.', BillNo, '`') 
     )  INTO @sql
FROM tbl_submit_coursefee
WHERE BatchID=@bid;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT TraineeID, ', @sql, ' 
            from tbl_submit_coursefee c
            where c.BatchID=@bid
            group by c.TraineeID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the quotes,
like this :

```
SET @sql 
= CONCAT('SELECT TraineeID, ', @sql, ' 
from tbl_submit_coursefee c 
where c.BatchID=''',BID,''' 
group by c.TraineeID');
```

according with doc : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: with this way query execute nicely but once it executes then `''' ,BID, ''';` change to `'' ,BID, '';` , finally this will not executes further.